# Why does BezierFunction not follow BezierCurve at npts>4?

Tags: graphics, splines

This example:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}};
f = BezierFunction[pts]
Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}],Graphics[{Blue, Dashed, BezierCurve[pts]}]]
```

perfectly works producing

[image: curves coincide]

However with

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
```

it produces

[image: curves do not coincide]

Why do the curves not coincide and how to access BezierFunction for BezierCurve with npts>4?

Answer (score 11):

`BezierCurve` normally gives a composition of local 4point-Bezierfunctions.

You get equal curves by setting   `SplineDegree->1+Length[pts]`

```
 Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Green, Line[pts]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
 Graphics[{Blue, Dashed,BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 1 + Length[pts]]}]]
```

[image]